# List the number of room online users with QuickBlox JS SDK

Tags: javascript, web, sdk, quickblox

I have tried my best to read their SDK but with No luck.   I think I have been able to join a chatroom using `QB.chat.muc.join(CHAT.roomJID, function() {}`.   All I want to do is to list the number of online users.   But no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's available since 1.13.0

http://quickblox.com/developers/Javascript#Download_JavaScript_SDK

```
var dialogJid = "...";

QB.chat.muc.listOnlineUsers(dialogJid, function(users) {

});
```

http://quickblox.com/developers/Web_XMPP_Chat_Sample#Get_online_users

Comment: Thanks a lot.   I'm actually just seeing your reply.   I'm gonna try it out